# "Armar un lío", es muy casual o apropriado para contenido formal?

Tags: formalidad

Puedo decir que `armar una lío` es una expresión completamente informal o no? Por ejemplo, si voy a contestar un correo de manera formal, ¿es apropiado?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A pesar de ser una expresión bastante coloquial e informal, no es tan inapropiada en el lenguaje formal como para no poder usarla.

Si quieres mantener un tono muy serio en el correo sustitúyela por otra expresión (como *causar problemas* o *aumentar la dificultad*), pero no necesariamente por incluirla va a causar mala impresión. Dentro de las expresiones coloquiales con este significado, esta es muy aceptable (no es grosera ni "barriobajera").

Comment: Yo coincido con tu respuesta sin embargo creo que también puedes coincidir en que muchas personas podrían considerarlo algo totalmente inaceptable en una redacción formal